# how to display a svg image in a blade.php file in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, svg, laravel-controller

I'm having my logo in `resources/layouts/inc/logo.blade.php` in `svg` format

Now I wanna display the logo in a pdf that I've created using `dompdf` in a `Controller`

in my `PdfController.php`

```
$output = '<div class="col-xs-12">
                    '.asset('layouts.inc.logo').'
          </div>'
```

But it just showing the url in the pdf

Comment: why would you put a svg in a .blade.php file? just save it als an .svg file, and add it as an `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

For dompdf best way is to copy the svg code into the pdf generating blade

example from my project below

```
 <img style="width: 140px;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3...." alt="" />
```